# Multiple highest weights of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, representation-theory, conformal-field-theory

I am trying to understand the following idea:

**The Setup:**

Consider the algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ with generators $\mathfrak{J}^0$,$\mathfrak{J}^{\pm}$. The algebra has the following commutation relations:
$$
[\mathfrak{J}^0,\mathfrak{J}^{\pm}]= \pm \, 2 \, \mathfrak{J}^{\pm}, \quad[\mathfrak{J}^+,\mathfrak{J}^-]=\mathfrak{J}^0
$$
Then select the highest weight state $|k\rangle$
$$
\mathfrak{J}^+ |k\rangle =0, \quad \mathfrak{J}^0 |k\rangle = k|k\rangle
$$
A module is spanned by the multiple application of lowering operators:
$$
|k,n\rangle = (\mathfrak{J}^-)^n |k\rangle
$$
Using the algebra relations one finds:
$$
\mathfrak{J}^+|k,n\rangle = n(k-(n-1))|k,n-1\rangle
$$
By construction $|k,0\rangle = |k\rangle$ is the highest weight.

**The confusion**

If $k \in \mathbb Z_{+}$ the state $|k,k+1\rangle$ is another highest weight with eigenvalue $k' = -2-k$ and therefore equivalent to $|k'\rangle$
$$
|k,k+1\rangle \hat{=} |-2-k\rangle
$$
The eigenvalue $k'$ of this highest weight is negative and the lower representation therefore irreducible.

I don't understand the last part.

**Edit:**
After the comments of Zachos and going through the calculation, I can see where the multiple highest weights come from.
Just require $(k-(n-1))=0$ for highest weights.

Like that:

moving like -> with J+

|3,5>   |3,4>   |3,3>   |3,2>   |3,1>   |3,0>

moving like <- with J-, you can move from |3,3> to |3,4> but the other way around is not possible.

**Nevertheless, I thought the highest weights are unique. How is this compatible with the highest weight theorem?**

The point of the paragraph is to introduce unitarity and multiplet shortening later.

Comment: Your "one finds" expression has an algebraic error. It does not vanish. Try *k=1* and ladder down two steps, and then up one. Your QM text should be bringing you up to speed... But that state is the lowest weight one... You might have to explain how you forfeit unitarity.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Upon calculating the expression for different values of $n$, including $n=1,2,3$, I did not encounter any algebraic errors. Why ist it the lowest weight one, because of negative weight? In my experience, the quantum mechanics books I have consulted did not explicitly address this aspect, especially in terms of unitary bounds.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator), after you translate to standard notation.

Comment: The point is your factor of 2 in the Lie algebra is in the ***wrong commutator*** , w.r.t. standard conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify notation, rename $\mathfrak{J}^0\mapsto J_0; ~~~\mathfrak{J}^{\pm}\mapsto J_{\pm}$, but move the 2 to the last commutator of charged generators, so the ladder ones move the eigenvalue of $J_0$ by one, not two!

Presumably you've learned that the operator
$$
J^2\equiv J_-J_+ +J_0^2+ J_0= J_+J_- +J_0^2-J_0  
$$
commutes with all tree Lie algebra elements above, so, it is simultaneously diagonalizable with them. One is interested in multiplets (modules) sharing eigenvalues of $J^2$, since the ladder operators cannot change those.

For simplicity, take $k=1$, and you may extend the following in the general case. You showed
$$
J_+|1\rangle =0, \qquad J_0|1\rangle = |1\rangle \leadsto \\
J_-J_+|1\rangle =0 = (J^2 -1-1)|1\rangle ~~~\implies J^2|1\rangle = 2|1\rangle ,\leadsto \\
J^2|1,n\rangle =2|1,n\rangle.
$$
Now, prove, by above,
$$
J_0|1,1\rangle =0, \qquad J_0|1,2\rangle =-|1,2\rangle ,\leadsto \\
J_+|1,2\rangle =2|1,1\rangle,
$$
non-vanishing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After carefully going through your steps I come to the same solution except for the last line I get:
$J_+ |1,2\rangle = J_+ J_- J_- |1\rangle = (J_- J_+ +2J_0 )J_- |1\rangle  = [J_- (J_- J_+ +2J_0 )+2(J_- J_0 - J_- )]|1\rangle  = (J_- J_- J_+ + 2J_- J_0 - 2 J_-)|1\rangle =0$

Comment: This is the mistake you keep making... Your last line is wrong, while the penultimate is right. The last line should be $2J_-J_0|1\rangle =2|1,1\rangle$, where I have omitted the vanishing terms!